# How to build Nested structure result from SQL join query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have Employee and Employee Detail tables in BigQuery. While Join these two tables using SQL queries, I want the result set like nested structure, EmployeeName and EmployeeDetails would be in single row.

Could you please give some idea to build this nested structure using query. Below query needs to be modify with nested structure result.

```
select EmployeeName, EmployeeDetail1, EmployeeDetail2 from Table1 t1, Table2 t2 where t1.Id = t2.Id
GROUP BY EmployeeName, EmployeeDetail1, EmployeeDetail2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT EmployeeName, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(EmployeeDetail1, EmployeeDetail2)) EmployeeDetails
FROM `project.dataset.Employee` t1
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.Details` t2 
USING(Id)
GROUP BY EmployeeName
```

Yo can test, play with above using [totally] dummy data as in below example

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.Employee` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS EmployeeName UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 3 
), `project.dataset.Details` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 11 AS EmployeeDetail1, 12 EmployeeDetail2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 21, 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 211, 221 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 212, 222 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 31, NULL 
)
SELECT EmployeeName, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(EmployeeDetail1, EmployeeDetail2)) EmployeeDetails
FROM `project.dataset.Employee` t1
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.Details` t2 
USING(Id)
GROUP BY EmployeeName
```

with result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It works. You and Martin Weitzmann answers are correct. You save me the day!

Comment: glad it helped. Please consider also voting up the answer ;o)

Answer (score 2):

I guess that would be

```
select EmployeeName, ARRAY_AGG(struct(EmployeeDetail1, EmployeeDetail2)) from Table1 t1, Table2 t2 where t1.Id = t2.Id
GROUP BY EmployeeName
```